# Easiest way to make post private by default

Tags: wp-admin

I don't know how to make a plugin so I can't do what's suggested here [How can I make it so the Add New Post page has Visibility set to Private by default?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15046/how-can-i-make-it-so-the-add-new-post-page-has-visibility-set-to-private-by-defau)

so what's alternative ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accepted solution is not the correct answer to change the visibility of any post type to any status. Below code is the right way to change the post status.

```
function set_post_type_status_private( $status, $post_id ) {
    $status = 'private';
    return $status;
}
add_filter( 'status_edit_pre', 'set_post_type_status_private', 10, 2 );
```

**Updated:**

The above filter will change the post status to *Private* when user will hit **Save Draft** or **Publish** button. So on edit page load if you see Status *Public* then don't worry.

There is one more filter available to change the status before saving into database. The filter is `status_save_pre` but I didn't find any documentation on [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/status_save_pre) so I wrote below code to test it.

```
function save_post_type_status_private( $status ) {
    $status = 'private';
    return $status;
}
add_filter( 'status_save_pre', 'save_post_type_status_private', 10, 1 );
```

The above filter saves the post as *Private* post type as soon as edit page load so one may want to use this filter over `status_edit_pre` but if I use `status_save_pre` filter I run into an issue, I can't delete any post. So I prefer 'status_edit_pre' over 'status_save_pre' until WordPress team fix this bug.

Answer (score 7):

Found this on [WordPress forums](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-set-new-post-visibility-to-private-by-default?replies=14#post-2074408):

You can just add this to functions.php. I've tested once and seemed to work fine.

```
function default_post_visibility(){
global $post;

if ( 'publish' == $post->post_status ) {
    $visibility = 'public';
    $visibility_trans = __('Public');
} elseif ( !empty( $post->post_password ) ) {
    $visibility = 'password';
    $visibility_trans = __('Password protected');
} elseif ( $post_type == 'post' && is_sticky( $post->ID ) ) {
    $visibility = 'public';
    $visibility_trans = __('Public, Sticky');
} else {
    $post->post_password = '';
    $visibility = 'private';
    $visibility_trans = __('Private');
} ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
        try {
            $('#post-visibility-display').text('<?php echo $visibility_trans; ?>');
            $('#hidden-post-visibility').val('<?php echo $visibility; ?>');
            $('#visibility-radio-<?php echo $visibility; ?>').attr('checked', true);
        } catch(err){}
    }) (jQuery);
</script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'post_submitbox_misc_actions' , 'default_post_visibility' );
```

Comment: Do not ever edit WP core files as an update will undo your changes. A plugin or themes function.php file is appropriate. Just adding this for newer WP developers.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative would be to find someone else to make a plugin.

If you're using WordPress.com (meaning you can't install arbitrary plugins on your site), then you're out of luck.  But for a self-hosted WordPress installation, you'll need to write a plugin and install it on your site.  There are no alternatives when it comes to adding custom functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer doesn't work for me. Here's a simple solution. It will only run the first time you publish any post.

```
function tse_make_post_private( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
  // check if is published and the post type is "post"
  if ( 'publish' === $new_status && $post->post_type === 'post' ) {
    // check if the post status is not private
    if ( $post->post_status != 'private' ) {
      // change the post status to private
      $post->post_status = 'private';
      // update the post
      wp_update_post( $post );
    }
  }
}
add_action('transition_post_status', 'tse_make_post_private', 10, 3);
```