# How can I make my blog private?

Tags: posts, plugin-recommendation, private

I want to create a blog to share with my family, but random Internet strangers should not be able to read the posts.

**How can I make posts hidden to the public, by default?** I know I can manually edit the visibility of single posts while I edit them - one at a time.

**Is there some global preference setting that I could set to "private"?** That would have the benefit of also working with the Wordpress app for iPhone, as well as the "post-by-mail" feature of Jetpack. Both of these would otherwise publish a normal, public post.

Several [old answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/private) mention variants of the outdated "Members only" plugin - but this is outdated so not an option, even though it might have been a good solution. This [plugin question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15046/how-can-i-make-it-so-the-add-new-post-page-has-visibility-set-to-private-by-defa) also has the same goal, but it's aimed at plugin development, and the answers don't apply.

**Is there really no (current) plugin that does this?**

Comment: What about <a href="http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/absolute-privacy/">Absolute Privacy « WordPress Plugins</a> ? You can require login and registration for all users. The plugin also disables RSS feeds.

Comment: Sorry, that plugin is also incompatible with newer WP versions. Last Updated: 2010-3-28: _"This plugin hasn't been updated in over 2 years. It may no longer be maintained or supported and may have compatibility issues when used with more recent versions of WordPress."_

Comment: http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/log/absolute-privacy/ revsion log states it was updated 3/12. I use the plugin all the time om 3.4+. See http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-absolute-privacy-is-this-plugin-save?replies=6

Comment: Password Protected - a simple free easy plugin:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/password-protected/ And it's updated regularly, last in Feb 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found something (I think): **[Network Privacy](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/network-privacy/)** is currently in version 0.1.4 but looks just about right.

When installed, there's a new *Privacy* setting screen where I can choose, e.g.

> I would like my site to be visible only to Site contributors.

Given that new users automatically get the permission level *Subscribers* when they sign up, this setting allows me to select among the registered users and promote them to the *Contributor* level.

When I visit the site without being logged in, or logged in as a Subscriber (lowest level of registered users) then I am redirected to the login screen that also includes the message:

> [My site] can be viewed only by contributors and above.
>   Subscribers and logged-out users are not able to view this site.